# iOS with Parse.com : save objects bidirectionally

Tags: ios, save, parse-platform

I have the following setup

```
@interface PMObject : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) PMUser *creator;

---

@interface PMUser : PFUser <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) PMObject *currentObject;
```

Reading about a similar problem from [this question](https://parse.com/questions/bidirectional-relationship-one-to-many) I am saving a new PMObject in the following way:

```
PMObject *object = [PMObject object];
[object setCreator:[PMUser currentUser]];

[object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

 if(succeeded){

    [[PMUser currentUser] setCurrentObject:object];

    //this point is reached as expected
    [[PMUser currentUser] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

       //this point is never reached ?

    }];

 }

}];
```

Regardless of how obvious this seems, it is not working as expected. Would be happy for any help !

Comment: Have you logged to check if you're getting success or failure?? If error, have it log and see what prints.

Comment: Yes, it is saving the PMObject successfully. See edits.

Comment: How is currentUser being computed/generated? From your code as posted, it should be working perfectly.

Comment: The code you see above is executed in the callback of - `(void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user;` i.e. just after login and I do verify the user is logged in properly

Comment: @DylanGattey You know what i tried - so just after the callback for saving the object returns, I make a query to fetch the exact same object, and then set is as the current object of the user. This works, but I dont think is a good solution.

Comment: Hmm. That'll work for sure, but not great. But you're saying it's actually getting saved? And the callback is the only thing that doesn't work?

Comment: Reason is that when outter saveinbackground is called it work's fine but for inner saveinbackground to be called ,it needs outter method to be alive which in this case is not as it has finished it job and when later inner is called there is no object alive. So u could use **[[PMUser currentUser] save]** method instead of saveinbackground. Give it a try and let me know !